# Angular4: How to set params with HttpParams?

Tags: angular, httpclient

So, migrated from http to httpClient and I am trying to use HttpParams to set the params for my get request....

The logic is very straightforward

```
const params = new HttpParams();

if(expression) {
    params.set('foo', 'bar');
}

this.http.get('url.json', {params: params});
```

This way the params are not passed through! the params.set('foo', 'bar'); does nothing.. (regardless of the condition met ;) )

If I do it like this though:

```
const params = new HttpParams().set('foo', 'bar');
```

foo is set!

How can I use HttpParams in my case (where some evaluating is involved)??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
let params = new HttpParams();

if(expression) {
    params = params.set('foo', 'bar');
}
```

API:

```
/**
* Construct a new body with a new value for the given parameter name.
*/
set(param: string, value: string): HttpParams;
```

Comment: believe me, tried with let, but it is not setting the value.... no matter how many times I set the params.set after, only the one concatenated to the constructor is set :/

Comment: forgot params = params.set('foo', 'bar')

Comment: @AntonLee   I  am facing same type of issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59517991/httpparams-doesnt-work-in-angular-getting-502-error?noredirect=1

can you help me if possible